# Java mouse listener: toggle version "click counter"

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I'm trying to make a basic click counter using mouse events in Java. I understand the tutorials everyone has but their programs are semi automatic and it registers one increment per click.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
   { 
       clicks++;
   }
```

I'm trying to do a fully automatic version of that where it will continually increment until you release the button, but the release method doesn't switch the boolean to false and stop the loop. Any advice?

```
public class example{
private boolean fire = false;
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
   { 
       if(e.getButton()== e.BUTTON1){fire = true};
       while(fire) {clickCounter++; }
    }
   }
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
       fire = false;
}
}
```

Comment: *"where it will continually increment until you release the button"* - How many clicks per second are you hoping for? You may also want to have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for reason why your current approach won't work

Comment: In my original code I have a sleep timer so it's 3 clicks per second after the increment in the while loop. I left that part out because it works, and isn't the problem so I didn't want to make my question sound confusing.

Comment: Sleeping and looping indefinitely in the Event Dispatching Thread is going to cause you the same issues

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, a "click" is what typically happens between the mouse been pressed and released, the idea that there are more "clicks" during this period is an artificial construct.

First, you need to go read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to better understand while "sleep" and `while-loop` won't work in this context.  You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing any new events from been processed.

The following example simply attempts to calculate the time between the mouse pressed and released event and applies a artificial multiplier to the result to create the "click" count

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("...");
            add(label);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                private LocalDateTime clickTime;

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    clickTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (clickTime == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Duration between = Duration.between(clickTime, LocalDateTime.now());
                    long seconds = between.getSeconds();
                    long clicks = seconds * 3;
                    label.setText("Held for " + seconds + "s = " + clicks + " clicks");
                    clickTime = null;
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Another solution might be to start a Swing `Timer` on mouse pressed and stop it on mouse released, allowing it to increment a value

Answer (score 0):

You set `fire= true` then enter into an infinite `while(true)` loop.

To fix this, modify the boolean statement of the while loop inside the loop itself.

```
while(fire) {
  count++;
  if (mouseReleased(eventMouseIsReleased))
    fire= false;
} // Check while(fire) but now it is false! Move on!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This won't work because the mousedReleased's parameter variable is local and can't be accessed in the Pressed method.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying, if I am not mistaken the way you have it `private boolean fire` is a class variable. The parameter of `mouseReleased` is `MouseEvent e` so you can call the method from within your other method passing the appropriate parameter in. I am not familiar with the `MouseEvent` class which is why I just wrote `eventMouseIsReleased` to represent the appropriate `MouseEvent`. My suggestion is missing a `)` which I will add.